# SQLRPGLE program running extremely slow on Prod server

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400, rpgle

I have built a subfile application as below. This code works fine on our Test server but when it was promoted to our Prod server, the application is performing extremely slow.

I have noticed that the CPU utilization is going high to 72% etc when the program is running on Production. Again not on our test server.

Would it be the SQL statements causing this issue? Would it be any file locks causing this issue in Production? However, the reading of the files in input mode should happen without issues I believe. The number of records in both the test and Prod versions of the files is almost the same.

```
¹**********************************************************************
  *           M a i n t e n a n c e    L o g
 ¹**********************************************************************
 ¹* itg #   date   prgmr     description
 ¹* ----- -------- -------  ----------------------------------------------
  * 43086 04/01/18 TXP1BAH  New program
 ¹**********************************************************************
¹
 ¹**********************************************************************
  *                File descriptions
 ¹**********************************************************************
 FMF552D09  CF   E             Workstn
 F                                     SFILE(SFILE01:SF1RRN)
 F                                     SFILE(ERRORSF:ERRRRN)
 F                                     Infds(Info)
 FQSYSPRT   O    F  132        Printer
 FFSFIC30   IF   E           K DISK
 faasecur   if   e           k disk
 ¹**********************************************************************
  *      Arrays
 ¹**********************************************************************
 D Msg             s             35    Dim(5)  ctdata perrcd(1)
 ¹**********************************************************************
  *                 Data structures
 ¹**********************************************************************
 DInfo             ds
 D Cfkey                 369    369

 D FSREC           ds                  likerec(FSFIP00A)
 d                sds
 d pgm               *proc
 d progn                   1     10
 d cent                  199    200  0
 d jname                 244    253
 d uname                 254    263
 d jnumb                 264    269
 d  #SDS_Date            276    281  0
 d   #SDS_Month          276    277  0
 d   #SDS_Day            278    279  0
 d   #SDS_Year           280    281  0
 d  #SDS_Time            282    287  0
  **********************************************************************
  *      Data Queue Layout
  **********************************************************************
 i/copy @dqlayc1

  **********************************************************************
  *      Stand Alone Variables
  **********************************************************************
 D ValidFlag       S              1    Inz(*Blanks)
 D Fstat           S              1    Inz(*Blanks)
 D ErrorFound      S               N   Inz(*Off)
 D Positioned      S               N   Inz(*Off)
 D PrPositioned    S               N   Inz(*Off)
 D Toggle          S               N   Inz(*Off)
 D OnHoldN         S               N   Inz(*Off)
 D ClearedN        S               N   Inz(*Off)
 D Updated         S               N   Inz(*Off)
 D Sseqnc          S              3
 D Rem             S              4  0
 D Qut             S              4  0
 D Sdatec          S              8
 D SavRrn          S                   Like(Sf1Rrn)  Inz(1)
 D SavRup          S                   Like(Sf1Rrn)  Inz(1)
 D MOMode          S             10    Inz('DISPLAY')
 d #event          S             10
 d #curr_date      s              8  0
 d #curr_time      s              6  0
 d RepStatus       s              1    Inz(' ')
 d Prdat           S              8  0
 d #group          s             10
 ¹**********************************************************************
  *      Constants
 ¹**********************************************************************
 D Moinquiry       C                   Const('7')
 D Hisinquiry      C                   Const('5')
 D ParmCorp        C                   Const('HF')
 D ParmDivi        C                   Const('30')
 D Refresh         C                   Const(X'35')
 D OnHold          C                   Const(X'3A')
 D Cleared         C                   Const(X'3B')
 D Reporting       C                   Const(X'36')
 D Enter           C                   Const(X'F1')
 D SflSize         C                   Const(9999)
 ¹**********************************************************************

 ¹**********************************************************************
  *      Procedures
 ¹**********************************************************************
  //  Procedure MOINQUIRY - M.O. MAINTENANCE Display Mode
 D MOINQUIRYPR     PR                  Extpgm('MOHD01')
 D                               10a   CONST
 D                               10a   CONST
 D                               10a   CONST
 D                                2a   CONST
 D                                7a   CONST
 D                                3a   CONST
 D                                3    CONST
 D                                7a   CONST
 D                                1a   CONST
  //  Procedure AASECGP - Retrieve Accouting Code
 d aasecgp         pr                  extpgm('AASECGP')
 d                               10a
 d                               10a

  //  Procedure HISTORYINQPR - Call MF040R08 Program
 D HISTORYINQPR    PR                  Extpgm('MF040R08')
 D                               10    CONST
 D                               10    CONST
 D                                1    CONST

  // Procedure IVDQP1 - Write Data Queue Record
 D ivdqp1          pr                  extpgm('IVDQP1')
 D                              646a   const

  // Procedure MF552R10 - Reporting
 D ReportPR        pr                  extpgm('MF552C10')
 D                                1a   const
 ¹**********************************************************************
  *                Main program logic
 ¹**********************************************************************

     Exsr Build_Subfile;

     DoU (*Inkc = *On);

       If (ErrorFound);

         *In91 = *on;
         Errrrn = 1;

       EndIf;
       Write Errorsfc;
       *In03 = *On;
         Exfmt SFCTL01;
       Select;
         // If refreshed, Clear Position to fields...
         When (Cfkey = Refresh);
           Exsr clrerrsf;
           Clear POMOS;
           Clear POAST;
           Clear POUNIT;
           Toggle = *Off;
           OnHoldN = *Off;
           ClearedN = *Off;
           Positioned = *Off;
           EXSR Clear_Sfile01;
           Exsr Build_Subfile;
           *In44 = *Off;

         //If toggle is on,set on appropriate indicators to display
         //only required rolls
         When (Cfkey = OnHold or Cfkey = Cleared);
           Exsr clrerrsf;
           Clear Pomos;
           Clear POAST;
           Clear Pounit;
           Toggle = *On;
           *In44 = *On;
           If (Cfkey = OnHold);
             OnHoldN = *On;
             ClearedN = *Off;
             Lstatus = 'Showing Only ON-HOLD/QC CHECK Rolls';
           EndIf;
           If (Cfkey = Cleared);
             ClearedN = *On;
             OnHoldN = *Off;
             Lstatus = 'Showing Only QC PASSED Rolls';
           EndIf;
           Exsr Build_Subfile;

         //Check Position to Fields...
         When ((Pomos <> *Blanks) or (POUNIT <> *Blanks)
               and CfKey = Enter);
           Exsr Build_Subfile;

         When (Cfkey = Reporting);
           //Display all Released/On-Hold rolls in report...
           If (Toggle = *Off);
             RepStatus = *Blanks;
           ElseIf (ClearedN = *On);
           //Display all Released rolls in report...
             RepStatus ='2';
           ElseIf (OnHoldN = *On);
           //Display all On-Hold rolls in report...
              RepStatus ='1';
           EndIf;
           ReportPR(RepStatus);

         When (Cfkey = Enter);
           //Positioned = *off;
           Exsr Process_Subfile;

       EndSl;
     Enddo;

     *Inlr = *On;

   //*******************************************************************
   //          clear Error Subfile/Error Indicators
   //*******************************************************************
   Begsr clrerrsf;

     ErrorFound = *Off;
     Errrrn = *zeros;
     Mesg   = *blanks;
     *In99  = *off;
     *In91 = *off;
     *in90 = *on;
     write errorsfc;
     *in90 = *off;

   Endsr;

   //*******************************************************************
   //          Clear Subfile
   //*******************************************************************

   Begsr Clear_Sfile01;
     Sf1rrn = *Zeros;
     *In01 = *On;
     Write Sfctl01;
     *In01 = *Off;
     Positioned = *Off;
     Clear Ssopt;
     RepStatus = *Blanks;
   EndSr;

   //*******************************************************************
   //          Build Subfile
   //*******************************************************************
   Begsr Build_Subfile;

     Exsr Clear_Sfile01;
     clear sssts;
     Setll (*loval) FSFIC30;
     Read FSFIC30;

     DoW ( Not %Eof(FSFIC30) and Sf1rrn < Sflsize);

       //Filter 1st Quality rolls destined to Stitching...
       If (FIPLNT = '032' and FIAL09 = '032' and
                 FISTAT < '30');

         SSPIEC = FIPIEC;
         SSORD# = FIMONO;
         SSASRT = FIMAST;
         SSSEQN = FIMRWK;

         If (FIRSTR = 'Q');
           SSSTS  = 'QC-CHECK';
         ElseIf (FIRSTR = 'X');
           SSSTS  = 'ON-HOLD';
         ElseIf (FIRSTR = 'P');
           SSSTS  = 'PASS';
         EndIf;
         Evalr SSROLL = %Trim(FIAL06);
         SSQTY  = FICRTQ;
         SSLOCA = FILOCA;

         PRDAT = 0;
         SSDATE = *Blanks;
         Exec Sql SELECT COALESCE(MAX(OECRDT),0) INTO :PRDAT
                  FROM CTOEP00 WHERE OEUNIT = :SSPIEC
                  AND OECODE IN ('FS4500','FS4510');
         ExSr Check_SqlCode;

         If (PRDAT > *Zeros);
           SSDATE = %Subst(%Char(PRDAT):5:2) + '/' +
                    %Subst(%Char(PRDAT):7:2) + '/' +
                    %Subst(%Char(PRDAT):3:2)  ;
         ElseIf (Prdat = *Zeros);

           Exec Sql SELECT COALESCE(MAX(FIDFDT),0) INTO :PRDAT
                   FROM FSFIP00 WHERE FIPIEC = :SSPIEC;
           ExSr Check_SqlCode;
           If (PRDAT > *Zeros and Firstr = 'X');
             SSDATE =        %Subst(%Char(PRDAT):5:2) + '/' +
                      %Subst(%Char(PRDAT):7:2) +  '/' +
                      %Subst(%Char(PRDAT):3:2)  ;
           EndIf;

         EndIf;

         If (Toggle = *Off);

           Sf1Rrn += 1;
           Write SFILE01;
         Elseif (OnholdN = *On);
           If (Firstr = 'X' OR Firstr = 'Q');
             Sf1Rrn += 1;
             Write SFILE01;
           ENDIf;
         Elseif (ClearedN = *On);
           If (Firstr = 'P');
             Sf1Rrn += 1;
             Write SFILE01;
           EndIf;

         EndIf;

         If (((Fimono = pomos and Fimast = POAST and
            pomos <> *Blanks and POAST <> *Blanks) or
            (Fipiec = POUNIT and pounit <> *Blanks)) and
            Positioned = *Off and CfKey = Enter);

           Positioned = *On;
           Savrrn = Sf1rrn;
           Clear Pomos;
           Clear POAST;
           Clear Pounit;

         EndIf;

       EndIf;

       Read FSFIC30;
       Clear SSSTS;
     EndDo;

     If (Sf1rrn > *Zeros);
       *In02 = *On;
       If (Positioned = *On);
         Sf1rrn = Savrrn;
         PrPositioned = *On;
       Else;
         Sf1rrn = 1;
       EndIf;

     Else;
       *In02 = *Off;
     EndIf;
     //Positioned = *Off;

     If (Updated = *On and Prpositioned = *Off);
       Rem = %Rem(Savrup:10);
       If ( Rem = 0);
         Sf1rrn = SavRup - 9;
       Else;
         Sf1Rrn = (SavRup - Rem) + 1;
       EndIf;

       If (Toggle = *On);
         Sf1rrn = 1;
       EndIf;
       Updated = *Off;
       Positioned = *off;
     Elseif (Updated = *On and Prpositioned = *On);
       Sf1rrn = Savrrn;
       PrPositioned = *Off;
       If (Toggle = *On);
         Sf1rrn = 1;
       EndIf;
       Updated = *Off;
     EndIf;

   EndSr;

   //*******************************************************************
   //          Process Subfile
   //*******************************************************************

   BegSr Process_Subfile;
     Exsr clrerrsf;
     ReadC Sfile01;
     Dow Not %Eof;

       Select;
         //If option 5 taken, call MO Inquiry program...
         When SSOPT = Moinquiry;

           Updated = *On;
           MoInquiryPR(ParmCorp:ParmDivi:'032':'FS':SSORD#:
                      SSASRT:SSEQNC:MOMODE:'1');
         //Event enquiry...
         When SSOPT = Hisinquiry;

           updated = *On;
           Savrup = Sf1rrn;
           HistoryInqPR(sspiec:' ':' ');
         //Release the roll...
         When SSOPT = 'P';

           If (*In31 = *Off);
             Mesg = Msg(03);
             Exsr write_error;
             ErrorFound = *On;
             LeaveSr;
           EndIf;

           Updated = *On;
           Savrup = Sf1rrn;
           //Display Error is already Released...
           Exec Sql Select FIRSTR into :fstat
                                  from FSFIP00
                    where FIPIEC = :SSPIEC ;
           ExSr Check_SqlCode;
           //If already released, display error...
           If (Fstat = 'P');
             Mesg = Msg(01);
             Erpiec = Sspiec;
             Exsr write_error;
             ErrorFound = *On;
           ElseIf (Fstat = *Blanks);
             Mesg = Msg(04);
             Erpiec = Sspiec;
             Exsr write_error;
             ErrorFound = *On;
           Else;

             Exec Sql Update FSFIP00 SET FIRSTR = 'P'
                              WHERE FIPIEC = :SSPIEC ;
             ExSr Check_SqlCode;

             Savrup = Sf1rrn;
             #event = 'FS4510    ';
             exsr Write_event;
           EndIf;
         //Hold the roll...
         When SSOPT = 'H';

           If (*In31 = *Off);
             Mesg = Msg(03);
             Exsr write_error;
             ErrorFound = *On;
             LeaveSr;
           EndIf;

           Updated = *On;
           Exec Sql Select FIRSTR into :fstat
                                  from FSFIP00
                    where FIPIEC = :SSPIEC ;
           ExSr Check_SqlCode;

           //Display Error if already Held...
           If (Fstat = 'X');
             Mesg = Msg(02);
             Erpiec = Sspiec;
             Exsr write_error;
             ErrorFound = *On;

           Else;

             Exec Sql Update FSFIP00 SET FIRSTR = 'X'
                              WHERE FIPIEC = :SSPIEC;
             ExSr Check_SqlCode;

             Savrup = Sf1rrn;
             #event = 'FS4500    ';
             exsr Write_event;
           EndIf;
       EndSl;
       ReadC Sfile01;
     EndDo;
     Exsr Build_Subfile;
   EndSr;

   //*******************************************************************
   //          Write Error Subfile
   //*******************************************************************
   Begsr write_error;

      *In99 = *On;
      Monitor;
        Errrrn += 1;
      On-Error;
        Errrrn = *Hival;
      EndMon;
      write errorsf;

   endsr;
   //*******************************************************************
   //      Write FS4510 or FS4500 Events
   //*******************************************************************
     Begsr Write_event;

       Clear c1dtaq;
       Clear FSREC;
       Exec Sql Select * into :Fsrec
                         from fsfip00
                        where fipiec = :sspiec;
       ExSr Check_SqlCode;

       c1aist = 'A';
       c1fmt  = 'C1';

       c1code = #event;
       c1usts = fsrec.fistat;
       c1levl = 'FS';
       c1wtyp = 'W';

       //Release event...
       If (#event = 'FS4510');
         c1flg1 = 'P';
       EndIf;

       //On-Hold event...
       If (#event = 'FS4500');
         c1flg1 = 'X';
       EndIf;

       c1unit = fsrec.fipiec;
       c1qty  = fsrec.ficrtq;
       c1qlty = fsrec.fiqual;
       c1shde = fsrec.fishac;
       c1plnt = fsrec.fiplnt;
       c1ownr = fsrec.fiownr;
       c1uom  = fsrec.fiuom;
       c1rscd = fsrec.firscd;
       c1sku  = fsrec.fisku;
       c1skua = fsrec.fifprd;
       c1otyp = fsrec.fial01;
       c1ownd = fsrec.fial08;
       c1styp = fsrec.fial02;
       c1ship = fsrec.fial09;
       c1igrp = fsrec.fial10;
       c1word = fsrec.fimono;
       c1wast = fsrec.fimast;
       c1wseq = fsrec.fimrwk;

       #curr_date  = %dec(%char(%date():*iso0):8:0);
       #curr_time  = %dec(%char(%time():*hms0):6:0);

       c1crtm = #curr_time;
       c1stdt = #curr_date;
       c1crdt = #curr_date;

       c1btdt = c1crdt;
       c1prog = progn;
       c1user = uname;

       IVDQP1(C1DTAQ);

     EndSr;

   //*******************************************************************
   //  Initialize Subroutine - Inzsr
   //*******************************************************************
     Begsr *inzsr;

       Exsr security;
       Ssplnt = Seiplt;

       //If plant 31, grant authority to hold/release rolls...
       If (Seiplt = '031');
         *In31 = *On;
       EndIf;

     EndSr;

   //*******************************************************************
   //       Security
   //*******************************************************************
   begsr security;

     #group= *blanks;
     AASECGP(uname:#group);

     chain (uname:progn) aasecura;

     if not %found(aasecur);
         chain (#group:progn) aasecura;
         if not %found(aasecur);
             exsr end_job;
         endif;
     endif;

   endsr;

   //*******************************************************************
   //       End Of Job
   //*******************************************************************
   begsr end_job;

       *inlr = *on;
       return;

   endsr;

   //*******************************************************************
   //  Check for SQL Errors
   //*******************************************************************

   BegSr Check_SqlCode;

         If SqlCod <> *Zero;
            If SqlCod <> 100;
               Except $ERR;
               Dump(a);
               *Inlr = *On;    // Halt indicator
               return;
            EndIf;
         EndIf;

   EndSr;

   //*******************************************************************
 OQSYSPRT   E            $ERR        2  1
 O                                         +  1 '************************'
 O                                         +  0 '************************'
 OQSYSPRT   E            $ERR           1
 O                                         +  1 'SQLAID='
 O                       SQLAID            +  1
 O          E            $ERR           1
 O                                         +  1 'SQLABC='
 O                       SQLABC            +  1
 O          E            $ERR           1
 O                                         +  1 'SQLCOD='
 O                       SQLCOD        L   +  1
 O          E            $ERR           1
 O                                         +  1 'SQLERL='
 O                       SQLERL        L   +  1
 O          E            $ERR           1
 O                                         +  1 'SQLERM='
 O                       SQLERM            +  1
 O          E            $ERR           1
 O                                         +  1 'SQLERP='
 O                       SQLERP            +  1
 O          E            $ERR           1
 O                                         +  1 'SQLER1='
 O                       SQLER1        L   +  1
 O          E            $ERR           1
 O                                         +  1 'SQLER2='
 O                       SQLER2        L   +  1
 O          E            $ERR           1
 O                                         +  1 'SQLER3='
 O                       SQLER3        L   +  1
 O          E            $ERR           1
 O                                         +  1 'SQLER4='
 O                       SQLER4        L   +  1
 O          E            $ERR           1
 O                                         +  1 'SQLER5='
 O                       SQLER5        L   +  1
 O          E            $ERR           1
 O                                         +  1 'SQLER6='
 O                       SQLER6        L   +  1
 O          E            $ERR           1
 O                                         +  1 'SQLWRN='
 O                       SQLWRN            +  1
 O          E            $ERR           1
 O                                         +  1 'SQLWN0='
 O                       SQLWN0            +  1
 O          E            $ERR           1
 O                                         +  1 'SQLWN1='
 O                       SQLWN1            +  1
 O          E            $ERR           1
 O                                         +  1 'SQLWN2='
 O                       SQLWN2            +  1
 O          E            $ERR           1
 O                                         +  1 'SQLWN3='
 O                       SQLWN3            +  1
 O          E            $ERR           1
 O                                         +  1 'SQLWN4='
 O                       SQLWN4            +  1
 O          E            $ERR           1
 O                                         +  1 'SQLWN5='
 O                       SQLWN5            +  1
 O          E            $ERR           1
 O                                         +  1 'SQLWN6='
 O                       SQLWN6            +  1
 O          E            $ERR           1
 O                                         +  1 'SQLWN7='
 O                       SQLWN7            +  1
 O          E            $ERR           1
 O                                         +  1 'SQLWN8='
 O                       SQLWN8            +  1
 O          E            $ERR           1
 O                                         +  1 'SQLWN9='
 O                       SQLWN9            +  1
 O          E            $ERR           1
 O                                         +  1 'SQLWNA='
 O                       SQLWNA            +  1
 O          E            $ERR           1
 O                                         +  1 'SQLSTT='
 O                       SQLSTT            +  1
 ¹**********************************************************************
  *      Error Message Array
 ¹**********************************************************************
**           ==== Error Messages ====
-Roll Already in PASSED State                                  01             01
-Roll Already in ON-HOLD State                                 02             02
No authority to update                                         03             03
Roll Not ON-HOLD to Pass                                       04             03
```

### Update

As was mentioned in the comments below, the SQL statements were converted to RPG and couple of new logical files were created for this. This now seems okay. But, still not sure how this works fine on the test server which is usually slower.

Comment: Just adding to this, I have noticed this slow behavior when the program is executed in Debug mode on our test server. But in Production still clueless.

Comment: The COALESCE ... FROM CTOEP00 looks most suspicious, because it's the only place that file is used and could be inefficient if OEUNIT and OECODE aren't indexed (although you did state the number of records were the same). Also, it's unusual (to me) seeing LR set and return within a subroutine, but don't see how it could be causing your scenario.

Comment: Would converting the read from ctoepoo to rpg help? As you said,  sqls on this file is slow even when strsql is used

Comment: Any help on converting this to rpg would be helpful as I used sql here because I am not that good at rpg for this

Comment: To rewrite (efficiently) in RPG would need to know what logical file (index) exists on  CTOEP00 by OEUNIT and OECODE.  Because your interactive SQL is also slow, I doubt one exists (otherwise OS400 would utilize it).   You should be able to use "CREATE INDEX" to make one, however. It may take a long time to create initially, but then subsequent look-ups should be faster. You can use DSPDBR to determine what logicals (indexes) already exist.

Comment: I created a new LF. The sql stuff is still not in my current organization. In my previous organization , sql was mandatorily used. Added a select/omit condition as well to it thus making the application faster. The same issue was there with sql on fsfip00. Changed that to RPG as well. The only SQL left is where user has to update through options taken on the subfile record. As that would not exceed 20 or 30 records, I hope I can get away with thta. As it is an update operation, this is something I cannot test. Will have to hold my breath till they try it out.

Comment: Good to hear (sorry didn't notice your update before responding to last comment, but will leave it there for posterity)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170946/discussion-between-theju112-and-richard-evans).

Comment: Something to look for may be to verify that SQL is running at the same logging level on both systems.  It's quite possible that something in the SQL statements is hammering the job log slowing it down as well.

Comment: In the wild its number of rows in table test server vs  prod server.  And why are you going after min and max with sql when RPGLE can read a logical in date sequence and get the answer with one io?

Answer (score 0):

Does your test server have any indexes on the table that your production server does not?

Try running the program in debug mode STRDBG UPDPROD(*YES) and see if the query optimizer recommends any indexes to build.